# How to use Cucumber to write an acceptance test at Feature level?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, agile, acceptance-testing, jbehave

JBehave is Java based & good for Java applications. JBehave also supports good HTML reporting. However, the problem with JBehave is that it only supports Story level and not Feature level.

Can any one here help me with a small explanation or documentation where I can understand how Cucumber supports Feature level?

Comment: JBehave and Cucumber aren't really that different; they just use different words to refer to a collection of Scenarios. JBehave's term seems less correct to me, but you can still use it just like you would Cucumber. Possibly this answer is the source of the misunderstanding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8304995/634576 I commented there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature is an implementation of a capability (a capability might need more than one feature).

Let's look at [Mike Cohn's description](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories) of a "story", since it's pretty good:

> User stories are short, simple descriptions of a feature told from the
>   perspective of the person who desires the new capability, usually a
>   user or customer of the system. They typically follow a simple
>   template:
>
> ```
> As a <type of user>, I want <some goal> so that <some reason>.
> ```

A good user story follows the [INVEST principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)), and this is where we start getting into scenarios:

- Independent, which means it can be delivered on its own

A story may have one or more *contexts* in which the feature is going to work. The contexts are by their nature independent of other contexts.

- Negotiable, so you can rewrite it

As you work through a story, you may find other contexts or outcomes that need to be considered. The capability which is the core of the feature is usually associated with the "when". For instance, if I wanted to be able to generate a report, the "when" would be, "When I generate the report..."

- Valuable, so it delivers value to stakeholders

There may be several stakeholders with different outcomes. For instance, sending an email to say that a cab's been booked is important, but so is sending the booking confirmation to the driver! By considering different stakeholders, we come up with the outcomes for the scenarios that need to be considered.

- Estimable, so you can estimate the size

If you can't estimate the size, try just getting one scenario working. This is the functional equivalent of Kent Beck's "spike". Incidentally the only reason you need an estimate is usually to work out whether it's worth doing, given other work that could be done, so treat this accordingly.

- Small, which (quick edit as I realised I missed this letter) means you should have some level of certainty about it.

I actually prefer people knowing they have some level of *uncertainty* about it, and look to get feedback ASAP. If you're really certain about it (eg: login) then it's OK for it to be bigger, because you'll need feedback less frequently; you know what "working" looks like.

- Testable, which means the related description must include enough to test it

Examples become tests as a nice by-product of this analysis.

Why do we do stories in the first place, though? Why not just deliver whole features?

It turns out that the work needed to get some features shipped ends up being pretty big, especially if you've got a lot of stakeholders involved, and we want to either slice them up so we can get value from them earlier, or we want to slice them so we can get feedback.

So a story might be a slice through a feature that can actually be shipped, or it might be something designed to get feedback.

Scenarios are a fantastic way of doing this! The feature can be narrowed down to the most valuable contexts, or different stakeholders whose outcomes need to be considered. Be careful not to eliminate stakeholders with transactional needs (the user at the ATM gets their money; the bank debits the account) or regulatory needs (the bank makes a major investment; the regulators see the change in capital reserves).

Scenarios aren't the *only* way of getting feedback on a feature. New UI? Hard-code it without any behaviour and show it to people. New report? Make up a mock copy. New feed that nobody's ever processed? Make a spike, see if you can get the information out of it that you think you can.

Otherwise, consider different contexts and stakeholders whose outcomes need to be considered, and consider different capabilities with their contexts and outcomes. Features implement the different requirements, whose behaviour is illustrated by the scenarios you've derived.

Since a story is a slice through a feature, and a feature implements a capability, this is a typical hierarchy:

- Stakeholder
- Goal
- Capability
- Feature
- Story
- Scenario

If you're trying to work out how to relate scenarios to stories and features, this isn't a bad way to go. You'll find it familiar if you look at [Gojko Adzic's "Impact Mapping"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0955683645) or [Matt Wynne's "Example Mapping"](https://cucumber.io/blog/2015/12/08/example-mapping-introduction) (I think we all got it from listening to Chris Matts).

Be careful because in reality this is a bit fuzzy; you'll make discoveries as you start to deliver, so don't break everything down ahead of time. I find capabilities make good planning-level artifacts, and are often associated pretty easily with "Epics". They also come with their own high-level tests: "Can our users do what they need to, for the contexts we need to consider, and the stakeholders whose outcomes are also needed?"

The trick with a story is to only consider what's *needed* to deliver value, until it's actually delivered... and then some of the rest will be the *next* thing that's needed, etc.

For more ideas, here's my blog on [capability-based planning and lightweight analysis](https://lizkeogh.com/2013/09/05/capability-based-planning-and-lightweight-analysis/), and another one on [splitting up stories](https://lizkeogh.com/2008/09/11/splitting-up-stories/).

For Cucumber, organize by capability and then (if you need to) by context, and tag your check-ins with the story number (most CI tools, electronic boards and version control systems support this). It's OK for a feature or story to create more scenarios.

Comment: Thank you Liz, I have not found such a beautiful blog so far and thanks for taking time to answer my question. Pretty clear and thoughtful explanation.